# Passing jQuery object property to function

Tags: jquery

```
    new $.Feed({
        container: "#us-feed",
        feedUrl: "http://www.somefeed.com/feed/",
        onFeedLoad: function(feedResult) {
            formatFeed(feedResult);
        }
    });
```

Pretty basic syntax question: what is the syntax to pass the `container` property to the formatFeed function for use as a variable?

Comment: what is this `$.Feed` plugin?

Comment: You can always the string directly to `formatFeed`. We need more information and a link to the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the current object with **this**:

```
new $.Feed({
    container: "#us-feed",
    feedUrl: "http://www.somefeed.com/feed/",
    onFeedLoad: function(feedResult) {
        formatFeed(feedResult, this.container);
    }
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, that depends a lot on where and how onFeedLoad is being called. If you want a safe solution just store the container text in a temporary variable as mcos already suggested:

```
var container = "#us-feed";
new $.Feed({
    container: container,
    feedUrl: "http://www.somefeed.com/feed/",
    onFeedLoad: function(feedResult) {
        formatFeed(feedResult, container);
    }
});
```

Comment: That depends on in which context the function is called. Do you know the plugin?

Comment: Thanks, I was blanking on basic jQuery logic.

Comment: Actually that's basic *JavaScript* logic ;)